# How do I make this IFERROR(OR function work?

Tags: excel, if-statement, worksheet-function

I have an Excel Worksheet that I would like to create an error message in certain cells if a statement is condition is not met.

Here are the cells contents

> A1 = Paste your image source with the format
>
> B1 = IFERROR(OR(FIND("=",A1),(FIND("1",A1)),LEN(A1)),("A1 must contain either an equals sign or a 1"))
>
> B2 = =IFERROR(OR(FIND("=",A2),(FIND("1",A2)))*LEN(A2),"A1 must contain either an equals sign or a 1")
>
> ---
>
> > B1 == My goal is to have it say "A1 must contain..." IF = or 1 exists, but currently, it only works if both = and 1 are present.
> >
> > B2 == The behavior for this cell gives me the length only when both = and 1 are present.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
  =IF(AND(ISERROR(FIND("1",A1)),ISERROR(FIND("=",A1))),"A1 must contain either an equals sign or a 1","OK")
```

Comment: it worked and I changed the static OK to checking length of A1. =IF(AND(ISERROR(FIND("1",A1)),ISERROR(FIND("=",A1))),"A1 must contain either an equals sign or a 1",LEN(A1))